# How to check if a table exists in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, h2, jooq

After opening a database connection, I want to check if the database is newly minted or not. I am using H2 which automatically creates a DB if one doesn't exist.

I tried this check:

`db.Public.PUBLIC.getTables().isEmpty()`

but that returns a static list of tables (without querying the schema in the database).

I could write raw SQL to get the table list, but that would be specific to the database engine. Is there a generic alternative in jOOQ?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use:

```
db.Public.PUBLIC.getTables().isEmpty()
```

Because generated meta information is not connected to the database. Instead, you may want to take a look at [`DSLContext.meta()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta()). In your case, you'd simply write:

```
DSL.using(configuration).meta().getTables().isEmpty();
```

If you run this test very often, that's of course not a very performant way of checking if there are any tables, as it will fetch *all* tables into memory just to run an `isEmpty()` check. I suggest issuing an actual query instead:

```
int numberOfTables =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(count())
   .from("information_schema.tables")
   .where("table_schema = 'PUBLIC'")
   .fetchOne(0, int.class);
```

A future jOOQ version (after 3.11) will be able to offer you actual object existence predicates that can be used in SQL or elsewhere:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8038

Comment: Ah thanks. Any chance you could add a performant shortcut? I don't want to write DB engine specific code; one of the main reasons why I am using jOOQ.

Comment: That use-case has not been mentioned a lot from jOOQ users, yet, although I think many users may have it. I'm more than happy to put feature requests on the road map, but let's discuss them on the [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user) first.